# Solving the problems by matrix in linear algebra

Tags: linear-algebra

I learned from the class that if you want to solve the problems by matrix in

linear algebra, the problem has to satisfy linearity(homogeneity,superposition).

However, linear systems equation like (x + 2y = 3, 4x + 5y = 6) do not satisfy

linearity because they do not satisfy homogeneity and superposition. But we can

solve this linear system by constructing matrix $$
    \begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 2 \\
    4 & 5 \\
    \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
    x\\
y\\
    \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}
    3\\
6\\
    \end{pmatrix}
$$and getting inverse of the matrix \begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 2 \\
    4 & 5 \\
    \end{pmatrix}.
In short, if I want to solve the problem using matrices, I learned that the problem needs to satisfy linearity but linear equations do not satisfy the linearity(superposition, homogeneity). So isn't it wrong to use matrix to solve the linear system problem?

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  Please use [MathJax](https://www.onemathematicalcat.org/MathJaxDocumentation/TeXSyntax.htm) to format your posts.  To begin with, surround math expressions (including numbers) with `$` signs and use `_` for subscripts.  `$x_1$` comes out as $x_1$.

Comment: Hi. People tend to include systems with the "right hand sides" equal to fixed numbers within the definition of linear systems as long as the "left hand sides" are linear functions of the variables. The reasons for this become more apparent after a bit of theory.

Answer (score 1):

It can be easy to confuse functions and equations at first.
A *function* can be linear, such as $f(x,y) = 2x + 3y$.
An *equation* can be homogeneous, such as $f(x,y) = 2x + 3y = 0$, or inhomogeneous, such as $f(x,y) = 2x + 3y = 7$, but both are called linear equations.
Systems of linear equations can be solved with matrices.  If the equations are homogeneous, then if you find a solution, any constant multiple of that solution is also a solution.  For example, $(-3, 2)$ is a solution to $2x + 3y = 0$, so $(-30, 20)$ is also a solution.  If you find two such solutions, the sum of those solutions is also a solution.

In more advanced math, some equations are called *linear* if they don't have constant terms and *affine* if they do.  Those handle slightly more complicated *functions*.

Some equations such as differential equations have functions as the unknown variables in them.  These equations are called linear and homogeneous if the sum of two solutions is another solution, and any constant multiple of a solution is a solution. Such a combination is called a linear superposition of solutions.  For example (don't worry about all the details, just the result): $y" + y = 0$ has $y = sin x$ as a solution and $y = cos x$ as another.  So $5 sin (x)$ is also a solution, as is $sin (x) + cos (x)$, as is $3 sin (x) + 5 cos (x)$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Then is it correct to say that (1) we use the term linear(which needs to satisfy two principle - superposition, homogeneity) to the function, not to the equation? (2) linear equations($2x + 3y = 5$) are the equations made by using the function that is linear($f(x,y) = 2x+3y$)?

Comment: Essentially, but as I wrote, people do refer to "linear equations" when a linear function equals a constant.

Answer (score 0):

The proposed system of linear equations can be written as
\begin{align*}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2\\
4 & 5
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
x\\
y
\end{bmatrix} =
\begin{bmatrix}
3\\
6
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}

Since the coefficient matrix is invertible, we have the following solution
\begin{align*}
\begin{bmatrix}
x\\
y
\end{bmatrix} =
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2\\
4 & 5
\end{bmatrix}^{-1}
\begin{bmatrix}
3\\
6
\end{bmatrix} =
-\frac{1}{3}
\begin{bmatrix}
5 & -2\\
-4 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
3\\
6
\end{bmatrix} =
\begin{bmatrix}
-1\\
2
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}
That is to say, the solution set is given by $S = \{(-1,2)\}$.

In general, given the system of linear equations
\begin{align*}
\begin{bmatrix}
a & b\\
c & d
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
x\\
y
\end{bmatrix} =
\begin{bmatrix}
e\\
f
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}
where $ad - bc \neq 0$, the solution can be written as
\begin{align*}
\begin{bmatrix}
x\\
y
\end{bmatrix} =
\frac{1}{ad-bc}
\begin{bmatrix}
d & -b\\
-c & a
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
e\\
f
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}

Another way to interpret such problem is the following.

Consider the basis $\mathcal{B} = \{(1,0),(0,1)\}$ such that $T:\mathbb{R}^{2}\to\mathbb{R}^{2}$ satisfies
\begin{align*}
[T]_{\mathcal{B}} =
\begin{bmatrix}
a & b\\
c & d
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}

Thus the proposed problem consists in verifying if $(e,f)\in T(\mathbb{R}^{2})$.